# Re-read php codes without reloading the page - is this possible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a page that reads my codes again from the top to check how many data are in my database. if it reaches 10, then i want to execute something, for example "truncate table".

This is my code now:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

    function loadlink()
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load.php",
            data: { action: 'pass any value if required' },
            success: function(theResponse) {
                // optional
                $('#displayMessage').html(theResponse);
                }
        });
    }


    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function(){
        loadlink() // this will run after every 10 seconds
     }, 500);

});
</script>

<div id="displayMessage">Result:<br></div>

<?php
error_reporting(0);

include('core/dbconnection.php');
#$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : ''; // optional
#$action = 'Power';
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_staff");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count <= '4'  ){
   //backflip
   echo "backflip";
}else{
  //wait10seconds,check again
  echo "Not 4";
}


?>
```

but it echo out twice

output:

Result:
Not 4
Not 4

Comment: yes, you need to use sockets

Comment: Format your code properly

Comment: Set this code in a controller method or an include, then use ajax.

Comment: Php is executed on server side. If you want to get this content without page reload use Ajax.

Comment: after 10 seconds the page will read the code again and check the count

Comment: Please read [ask] then provide a properly detailed explanation of your issue

Comment: You need to make an ajax request to do that. Find a simple tutorial, it'll show you what to do. And please stop using the `mysql_` database library and switch to using `PDO` or `mysqli_` as soon as possible, `mysql_` was discontinued many years ago, and removed entirely in PHP7. It has many security vulnerabilities and doesn't support things like parameterised queries to protect you from SQL injection attacks. Also if you ever upgrade to PHP7 your code will stop working completely. No new code should be written using `mysql_` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**load.php**

```
<?php
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : ''; // optional

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_x");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count = 10){
   //backflip
}else{
  //wait10seconds,check again
}
?>
```

**main file**

the ajax will run after every 10 seconds to call load.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

    function loadlink()
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load.php",
            data: { action: 'pass any value if required' },
            success: function(theResponse) {
                // optional
                $('#displayMessage').html(theResponse);
                }
        });
    }


    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function(){
        loadlink() // this will run after every 10 seconds
    }, 10000);

});
</script>

<div id="displayMessage"><!--optional--></div>
```

Note:

> The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

MySQLi tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: I tried your code, thanks a lot, 
now my problem is , it echos 2 data in 


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_staff");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count <= '4'  ){
   //backflip
   echo "backflip";
}else{
  //wait10seconds,check again
  echo "Not 4";
}


Result:
Not 4
Not 4

Comment: `echo date('Ymd-h:i:s A', time()).' Not 4';` check whether the datetime 2 times same value or different

Comment: also do echo the query; maybe ajax call 2 times or query runs 2 times; Try to find out which part the query runs 2 times;

Comment: try to figure out the issue by using alert, echo in appropriate places for debugging; if cannot post another question with your latest codes;

Comment: you should have to post separately, because this question already got down vote. and nobody notice